Firestore Error: Document Not Found Despite Read Permissions
I'm facing an issue with Firestore in my Flutter application. I'm trying to access a document in my "users" collection using the recipient's userID, but I keep getting an error [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found. even though I've allowed read and write access in my Firestore rules.
Future<void> performTransaction(
      BuildContext context, double montant, String recipientUserId) async {
    String? senderUserId =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid; // Utiliser le userID Firebase
    // Exemple de code Dart pour obtenir un token d'accès Firebase
    String? idToken = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken();
    print(idToken);

    // Vérifiez que le senderUserId n'est pas null
    if (senderUserId == null) {
      print('Sender UserID not found.');
      return;
    }

    print('Sender UserID: $senderUserId');
    print('Recipient UserID: $recipientUserId');

    try {
      // Référence au document de l'expéditeur (sender)
      DocumentReference senderRef =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(senderUserId);

      // Référence au document du destinataire (recipient) en utilisant recipientUserId
      DocumentReference recipientRef =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(recipientUserId);

      // Fetch sender document
      DocumentSnapshot senderSnapshot = await senderRef.get();
      print('Sender document: ${senderSnapshot.data()}');

      // Fetch recipient document
      DocumentSnapshot recipientSnapshot = await recipientRef.get();
      print('Recipient document: ${recipientSnapshot.data()}');

      // Vérifiez que les documents existent
      if (!senderSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Sender document not found: $senderUserId');
        throw Exception('Sender not found');
      }

      if (!recipientSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Recipient document not found: $recipientUserId');
        throw Exception('Recipient not found');
      }

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        // Réobtenir les snapshots dans la transaction
        DocumentSnapshot senderSnapshot = await transaction.get(senderRef);
        DocumentSnapshot recipientSnapshot =
            await transaction.get(recipientRef);

        print('Current User ID: ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}');
        print('Recipient User ID: $recipientUserId');

        double senderBalance = senderSnapshot['balance'];
        double recipientBalance = recipientSnapshot['balance'];

        // Vérifiez que le solde de l'expéditeur est suffisant
        if (senderBalance < montant) {
          throw Exception('Insufficient funds');
        }

        // Mettre à jour les balances
        transaction.update(senderRef, {'balance': senderBalance - montant});
        transaction
            .update(recipientRef, {'balance': recipientBalance + montant});
      });

      print('Transaction successful');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Transaction failed: $e');
    }
  }

Despite setting Firestore rules to allow read and write access, I continue to receive a document not found error when trying to access the recipient's document using their userID (recipientUserId). I've verified the existence of the document in the Firestore collection.
I've double-checked the Firestore rules, ensured the correctness of the userID, and verified the document's existence through Firestore console. Is there anything I might be missing or any alternative approaches to troubleshoot this issue effectively?

can you share your database and are you sure the recipientUserId is not null?
